# Prevent duplication of element id in .push() in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of objects which is called users and it's defined in my component as `users: Array<GroupUser> = [];`, my goal is to check if new applicant doesn't have the same id as any of users that are already present in array.

Here is my model for GroupUser:

```
export class GroupUser {
  id?: number;
  user: number;
  permissions: string;
  confirmed?: boolean;
}
```

I receive applicant's data with id that you manually type in input from backend in this function:

```
onKey(event: any) {
  this.adminId = event.target.value;
  this.authService.getSpecUser(this.adminId).subscribe(
    (data => {
      this.admin = data;
    })
  );
}
```

So basically I want to check if adminId (`adminId: number;` in my component) equals to any users.user value that are already present in my array.

I've tried to use different functions to achieve the result:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
    if (this.admins.indexOf(this.users[i]) !== -1) {
      this.users.push({user: this.adminId, permissions: this.g.admin_rights.value});
    }
  }

for (let i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
       console.log(this.users[i].user, this.adminId)
       if (this.users[i].user != this.adminId) {
         this.users.push({user: this.adminId, permissions: this.g.admin_rights.value});
      }
     }
```

But new users are being added to array even if they have the same id. I think some() method can help but I'm not sure how to use it correct here.

So basically I'm trying to check if user is already in group before adding him there. There are a lot of users on platform and many groups for these users and before I'm adding new user to group and I must check if he is already there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are `this.admin` and `this.admins`? How do they relate to `this.adminId` and `this.users`? You could show the declaration of all these properties in their respective classes, instead of explaining it in text.

Comment: These are the values I'm using in test purposes:`admin: object = null;
 admins: Array<object> = [];`

Comment: @LogicBlower - Two users with the same `id` can be added to a `Set`, since they are different objects.

Comment: Id and user (in GroupUser class) must be unique and 2 other values mustn't be unique

Comment: @LogicBlower - If your question is about the `Set`, two objects with the same property values are still different objects. So they can be in the same `Set`. In other words `obj1 !== obj2`, even if all the property values are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use array `some()` in the following way

```js
var input = [
  { id: 1, user: 32, permissions: 'sample', confirmed: false },
  { id: 2, user: 41, permissions: 'sample', confirmed: false },
  { id: 3, user: 12, permissions: 'sample', confirmed: false },
  { id: 4, user: 5, permissions: 'sample', confirmed: false },
  { id: 5, user: 78, permissions: 'sample', confirmed: false }
];

var found = (input, adminId) => input.some(user => user.user === adminId);

if (!found(input, 41)) {  // don't push
  input.push({ id: 5, user: 41, permissions: 'sample', confirmed: false })
}
if (!found(input, 62)) {  // push
  input.push({ id: 6, user: 62, permissions: 'sample', confirmed: false })
}
if (!found(input, 62)) {  // don't push
  input.push({ id: 2, user: 62, permissions: 'sample', confirmed: false })
}
if (!found(input, 17)) {  // push
  input.push({ id: 6, user: 17, permissions: 'sample', confirmed: false })
}

console.log(input);
```

For your use case it might be used as

```js
if(!this.users.some(user => user.user === this.adminId)) {
  this.users.push({user: this.adminId, permissions: this.g.admin_rights.value});
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is just what I was trying to do

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the new user ONLY after you have checked all of them. instead you have it in the middle of your for loop, so it's going to add it over and over.

try this:

```
var doesExistFlag = false;
for (let i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
   if (this.users[i].user == this.adminId) {
     doesExistFlag = true;
   }
 }

if(!doesExistFlag)
   this.users.push({user: this.adminId, permissions: this.g.admin_rights.value});
```

an even better solution would be to generate a random id based on timestamp.

Comment: Why on earth a random ID?

Comment: isn't he trying to create a unique id for each user?

Comment: Thank you Rick, flag works well, but I thought I can do it in `for` loop or with the help of `some()` method. I'm not trying to create a unique id for each user, these users already exists in database and I'm just trying to check if user is already in group before adding him there. So basically I'm adding new user to group and I must check if he is already there.

Answer (score 0):

`id` is the name of the field ...which is never being compared to.

`adminId` probably should be `userId`, for the sake of readability.

While frankly speaking, just sort it on the server-side already.